# Conditional rendering inside v-for with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

### Problem

I'm building a project with Vue, where I have a list of projects, each with an open and delete button. Now I need to add Tags to each project with a separate component. I want to toggle this component's rendering for each list item individually to create a list with collapsable items.

My first try looked something like this:

```
<b-list-group v-if="!isLoading">
    <b-list-group-item v-for="project in projects" :key="project.path"> 
      {{ project.name }} 
      <b-btn variant="danger" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="deleteProject(project.path)">Löschen</b-btn>
      <b-btn variant="secondary" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="openProject(project.path)">Öffnen</b-btn>
      <b-btn variant="secondary" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="project.showTags = !project.showTags">Tags</b-btn>
      <search-tags v-if="project.showTags" style="margin-top: 1em;"></search-tags>
    </b-list-group-item>
```

If I console.log my `this.projects`, I can see that the value for each project changes correctly. Nevertheless, the v-if doesn't render even if `project.showTags == true`.

I then read, that you're not supposed to use `v-if` inside `v-for`, so I tried the Bootstrap-Vue [collapse](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse) component:

```
<b-list-group v-if="!isLoading">
    <b-list-group-item v-for="project in projects" :key="project.path"> 
      {{ project.name }} 
      <b-btn variant="danger" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="deleteProject(project.path)">Löschen</b-btn>
      <b-btn variant="secondary" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="openProject(project.path)">Öffnen</b-btn>
      <b-btn variant="secondary" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="project.showTags = !project.showTags">Tags</b-btn>
      <b-collapse v-model="project.showTags">
        <search-tags style="margin-top: 1em;"></search-tags>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-list-group-item>
```

But this also dosen't work.

I think this cannot be so difficult and I'm missing something here. Any help is appreciated.

### Edit 1

As seen in my code, the whole list is put inside `<b-list-group>` which is conditionally rendered depending on `isLoading`. If I force a reload by flipping `isLoading`, then flipping `project.showTags` and then flipping `isLoading` back, it works. But I feel like this solution is super shady and hacky.

Working but ugly code:

```
<b-list-group-item v-for="project in projects" :key="project.path"> 
      {{ project.name }} 
      <b-btn variant="danger" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="deleteProject(project.path)">Löschen</b-btn>
      <b-btn variant="secondary" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="openProject(project.path)">Öffnen</b-btn>
      <b-btn variant="secondary" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="test(project)">Tags</b-btn>
      <search-tags v-show="project.showTags" style="margin-top: 1em;"></search-tags>
    </b-list-group-item>
  </b-list-group>
```

with:

```
test(project) {
  this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;
  project.showTags = !project.showTags;
  console.log(this.projects);
  this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;
},
```

### Edit 2

My data is first defined like this:

```
data() {
return {
  projects: [],
  tags: [],
  newProject: false,
  isLoading: true,
  isError: false,
  form: {
    name: '',
  },
};
```

},

then on `created()` I call `getAllProjects()` to fetch my projects form backend:

```
created() {
this.getAllProjects();
},
```

My projects come without the `showTags` prop, so I assign it directly after fetching:

```
async getAllProjects() {
  try {
    this.isLoading = true;
    const res = await fetch(store.state.urlEndpoints.getProjects, {
      ...AuthPost(), // request config object
    });

    this.projects = JSON.parse(await res.text());
    this.projects.forEach((project) => { project.showTags = false; });
    console.log(this.projects);
    this.isLoading = false;
  } catch (err) {
    this.isError = true;
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
},
```

I console.log `this.projects` on each click on the "Tags" button, as seen above in the `test()` function. The values flip just like I intend them to.

Comment: How is `projects` defined? When you assign a value to it, does each item (`project`) have a `showTags` property (either `true` or `false`)?

Comment: @Phil yes, exactly. `projects` is an array of objects, each `project` has a property `showTags` initialized as `false` and flipped by the `@click`. The `projects` array is behaving exactly like I want it to, the element inside the v-for loop is just not responding to the change. As you can see, the whole thing is wrapped inside a `b-list-group` which is also rendered conditionally. If I force a rerender of the list with flipping `isLoading` twice, everything works. But I feel like this is a super wonky solution.

Comment: There's no problem here ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-swanson-63kop?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: my first thought was that it didn't react deep enough: refer to this link: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: How is your data defined? Could you do it with `v-if="projects.length > 0"`?

Comment: Please show how you define `projects`. My guess is that the `showTags` property is not reactive for some reason, usually because it is not defined at the time you assign a value to `this.projects`

Comment: I posted another edit, maybe this clears things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rouben you need to sort how you want to set `this.projects` as right now in your `created` you assume that you'll get the fixed array of projects back from `getAllProjects`.

Try doing something like this:

```
async getAllProjects() {
  try {
    this.isLoading = true;
    const res = await fetch(store.state.urlEndpoints.getProjects, {
      ...AuthPost(), // request config object
    });

    return await res.json().map(project => {
         project.showTags = false;
         return project;
    });
```

also you could try this instead inside the @click:

```
<b-list-group-item v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="project.path"> 
  {{ project.name }} 
  <b-btn variant="danger" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="deleteProject(project.path)">Löschen</b-btn>
  <b-btn variant="secondary" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="openProject(project.path)">Öffnen</b-btn>
  <b-btn variant="secondary" size="sm" class="list-button" @click="flipShowTags(index, project)">Tags</b-btn>
  <search-tags v-show="project.showTags" style="margin-top: 1em;"></search-tags>
</b-list-group-item>
```

```
methods: {
  flipShowTags(index, obj) {
    this.$set(this.projects, index, {...obj, showTags: !obj.showTags})
  }
}
```

if it was because of it not being reactive

Comment: Thanks! The `created()` was a dumb mistake, thanks for pointing that out! It didn't change the behavior though, but the `this.$set` solved my issue.

Comment: @Rouben nothing wrong with the way you're using `created()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here...

> ```js
> this.projects = JSON.parse(await res.text());
> this.projects.forEach((project) => { project.showTags = false; });
> ```

Adding the `showTags` property like this is not reactive which is why Vue doesn't react as you expect to changes.

See [*Change Detection Caveats*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

> Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.

You need to have all reactive properties present when you **assign** the value to your `projects` data property. For example

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    projects: [],
    isLoading: true,
    // etc
  }),
  methods: {
    async loadAllProjects () {
      try {
        this.isLoading = true;
        const res = await fetch(store.state.urlEndpoints.getProjects, {
          ...AuthPost(), // request config object
        });

        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`)
        }
    
        // note that the value assigned to `this.projects` now has the
        // `showTags` property at the time of assignment
        this.projects = (await res.json()).map(project => ({
          ...project,
          showTags: false
        }))
      } catch (err) {
        this.isError = true;
      }
      this.isLoading = false
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.loadAllProjects()
  }
}
```